# Ajax autocomplete url problem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Hey Guys.
  I have got a problem on using the jquery auto-complete plugin.my problem is as the downside.
  I am using the ruby on rails framework to develop project.

```
    $().ready(function() {
    $("#person_name").focus().autocomplete('show_people', {multiple: false, formatItem: formatItem, width: 290}).result(function(event,item){}
  }
```

this is my javascript code. i am on the page ..../conversations/23.  but when i use the auto-complete .the code send a request to /conversations/23/show_people. i don't want it send the request .i want it send the search request to /conversations/show_people.
  thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So specify the URL as "/conversations/show_people" instead of just "show_people"

Comment: I had already used the style ,but when i use this style ,the jquery do not send any request to the server

Answer (score 1):

First, update your autocomplete plugin to the latest version (the latest version is in jQuery UI) :

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete

And after you've upgraded, test using the new syntax which is like :

```
$("#my_input").autocomplete({ source: "/url", ... });
```